# Apache Camel - Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: apache-camel

It seems like some internal class from Apache Camel has a wrong implementation of Comparator for the `GenericFile` class.

I'm using Apache Camel version `2.17.3`, but the same problem happens with `2.18.3` as well.

I realize it's happening only in one scenario:

I have one processor which watch a directory (and sub-directories) looking for zip files, when they are found it extract them to another directory.

And another processor which watch the extracted directory, looking for any kind of files there.

e.g:

```
+ folder
  + sub1
    - zip1.zip
  + sub2
    - zip2.zip
+ extracted
  + zip1
    - <files from zip1.zip>
  + zip2
    - <files from zip2.zip>
```

The problem happens when zip1.zip and zip2.zip have packed files with the same name.

e.g.:

```
- zip1.zip
  - a1.txt
  - a2.txt 
- zip2.zip
  - a1.txt
  - a2.txt
```

Even I extracting them in different folders, it's messing something inside Camel. Here is the StackTrace:

```
2017-04-03T14:08:18.846 WARN  - [Camel (CORE-AARE) thread #16 - file://...] - [org.apache.camel.component.file.FileConsumer] - Consumer Consumer[file://...] Will try again at next poll. Caused by: [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - Comparison method violates its general contract!] 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
at java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(TimSort.java:899)
at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:516)
at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:441)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:245)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1512)
at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1454)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:175)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:152)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:175)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:102)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I got the same problem using the latest version `2.18.3`.

Comment: Can you explain what is your question? What problem do you want to solve?